# Is there a specific way of using nativescript-videorecorder plugin to work with angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am unable to get the nativescript-videorecorder to work in my app.

I had installed the plugin and used the code given on the github https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder for typescript. I created a simple HTML ui and tried to call a function to open the camera to record video. However it is does not work

For app.component.html i used the tag `<Image src="videoCam" (tap)="onCam()">`

For app.component.ts i used the below code

```
import { VideoRecorder, Options as VideoRecorderOptions } from 'nativescript-videorecorder';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent { 
    export class AppComponent { 
    onCam() {
        const options: VideoRecorderOptions = {
            hd: true
            saveToGallery: true
        };
        const videorecorder = new VideoRecorder(options);

        videorecorder.record().then((data) => {
            console.log(data.file)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
}
```

Is there anything i am missing to get this to work ?

Comment: Are you using a device for testing? Is it iOS / Android you are trying now?

Comment: I am using android phone with Nativescript playground app.

Comment: Sorry, that plugin is not compatible with Playground. Playground only works with plugins those require just JavaScript code, this particular plugin has a Java dependency so it may not work. Try it on your local machine.

Comment: @Manoj thank you for your answer. Is it worth trying to build it as an apk using "tns build android" and then test it. Apart from testing in the emulator locally ?

Comment: Yes it is. It doesn't work with Playground only because any Java dependency needs to go through compilation and rebuild the APK. If you do it locally, you can of course build the APK and run it on any device or even connect your device and directly run on it.

Comment: I will give it a try and update.